# Différence entre les suffixes -ique et -logie

Tags: étymologie

Certaines branches de la philosophie utilisent le suffixe -ique (du grec -ικός) et d'autres par -logie (du grec -λογία).

Y a-t-il une raison pour laquelle æsthétique et métaphysique n'ont pas de suffixe commun avec épistémologie? Peut-être une nuance dans le sens?

En particulier je me serais attendu à «logologie» et autre «metaphysicologie».

Answer (score 4):

Si je ne me trompe pas, le suffixe "logie" est utilisé pour décrire une science. Exemple : psychologie, ophtalmologie, gynécologie, sociologie... Etc.
Le suffixe "ique" pourrait être utilisé pour créer des adjectifs pour quelque chose qui a une relation avec cette science ou domaine d'études. Exemple : psychique, ophtalmologique, gynécologique, sociologique.

Comment: Si ce raisonnement était valide, la physique ne serait pas une science.

Comment: La différence se fait sur les sciences fondamentales définies du temps de Socrate, et les néo-***logi[e]***-smes qui jargonnent afin de casser l’unité des sciences fondamentales qui ne peuvent être accessibles par la seule raison, qui nécessitent l’intuition d’une conscience affinée. Les *-logies* sont plus proches des techniques et savoirs (liées aux sciences auxquelles elles se référent) qu’aux connaissances rattachées aux capacités de discerner ce qui vient des sens et à la pure -***logi[e]***-que de l’intelligence.

Comment: Un ajout, bon liens vers des explications qui vont de pair avec votre réponse; https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-logie et https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ique

Comment: Malheureusement cette belle thèse ne passe pas l'épreuve de la réalité, je reprends mon exemple épistémologie (que je n'imagine pas défini par Socrate)/métaphysique (qui, plus que la première, est accessible par la seule raison).

Comment: *Psychique* Qui appartient au psychisme, qui concerne **l'esprit, la pensée**. Synon. mental, ***psychologique***; anton. organique, physiologique, physique, somatique.Une impulsion psychique secrète qui est la parole d'avant les mots (Artaud, Théâtre et son double,1938, p. 72). Trois stades de l'évolution psychique, − ***inconscience, conscience du monde, conscience de soi*** — — —
*Psychologie* **Science qui étudie les faits psychiques**. En psychologie il n'y a pas de ***sentiments*** simples. Proust a fourni à la psychologie ***des documents*** infiniment précieux.

Comment: Où veux-tu en venir? J'ai déjà consulté le CNRTL.

Comment: Rapproche les définitions données par le CNTRL des mots cités dans ta question de mes deux réponses … Puisqu’il s’agit de philosophie la thèse est le fruit du mental, des mots, la réalité est inaccessible à celle-là et à ces derniers, la philosophie platonicienne n’en a qu’une vision partielle, Socrate, Empédocle, Héraclite et même Homère en ont manifesté son unité.